# How To Calculate Distance Between Two Points in Driving Direction Mode in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, mapping, driving-directions

everyone... 
I have something to ask about using a MapView in Android with Google Maps API..

I've read about how to make a Geopoint or more and find a distance between 2 points..

One thing that still makes me confuse is about calculating a distance between 2 points. I've tried and find the result but it's applied if the condition is when I want to make a straight line between those points. But, when I crosscheck with maps.google.com, the result (distance) is different with the same latitude and longitude of those points. And I realize that its a kind of a Driving Direction..

[example of Google Map Web](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=-7.963292,%20112.608129&daddr=-7.96583,%20112.607633&hl=en&geocode=FWR9hv8dgUO2Bg;FXpzhv8dkUG2Bg&mra=ls&sll=-7.963899,112.608469&sspn=0.002614,0.005284&ie=UTF8&ll=-7.964308,112.608774&spn=0.002614,0.005284&z=18)

If you see the picture, it's not a straight line so of course the distance is different. So how could I calculate this distance in Android in this case? And please show me the code to make it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will return you the straight line distance between two point..
you can use Google direction API for this ...Here is the link for this.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: see here is the distance tag which you have parsed to show the distance ...."distance": {
        "value": 2137146,
        "text": "1,328 mi"
      }, Here value is the distance in meter.

Comment: @Sujit: I mean how can I use that value in Java code?? I'v read the link but it looks like the output is in JSON or XML format..

So how I do that since I still don't know a lot about JSON and XML...

Comment: you have to use JSON parser or XML parser to retrieve the value .

Comment: if you don't mind, would you show the simple example of using XML parser?

Comment: Here are few link for using SAX parser in android         http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/sample-saxparser-in-android.html  http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: ok, I got it... 
but, based on this link that I generate with Google API Direction in XML format: [The result in XML Format](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Jalan+Candi+3E&destination=Jalan+Candi+3F&sensor=false)  

There are 3 tags <distance></distance> in that link... 
I still don't have any idea about which one I need...
Should I just use one of them?? 
or should I calculate three of them???

Comment: distance having value =328 and text = 0.3 km is your correct distance here . Rest of the distance are inside <step></step> tag . so it is basically the step by step distance.

Comment: I also want the 'value' not the 'text'... Based on that link, the 'value' and 'text' are child node of 'distance'. And as you can see, the 'value' is not only the child node of 'distance' but also 'duration'. So, how do I get the 'value' of 'distance'?

Comment: Hello. Is an sdk available for this?