# Location Manager

Tags: java, android, location

Can we use android location https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

inside the java standalone application. I have to find the distance between two lat/lng pairs. Now i am using

```
public double Haversine(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2)
    {
        double R = 6372.8; // Earth Radius in Kilometers

        double dLat = Deg2Rad(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Deg2Rad(lon2 - lon1);

        double a = (Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat2)) *
                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2));
        double c = (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)));
        double d = R * c;
        // Return Distance in Kilometers
        return d;
    }
    public double  Deg2Rad( double deg) {
 public double  Deg2Rad( double deg) {
        return  (deg * Math.PI / 180);
    }
```

But the above code gives the air distance. But i need roadway distance. Please help me out.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google direction API for this. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

I think you will find this helpful
[How To Calculate Distance Between Two Points in Driving Direction Mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328896/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-driving-direction-mode-in-androi)

Comment: is this working on java standalone application. we just add android.jar file is enough for this scenario.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Directions API of Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Good example is : http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

This is example of Distance API of Google Map, but you can refer to it and use Directions API in same way

Comment: say if we have 200 devices means 200 api calls to google which is performance overhead right?

Comment: 200 devices calls API using their API_KEY provided by Google from Google Developer Console. Every API_KEY is mapped with SH1 fingerprint of device and package name of application. So, Google manages these calls from different devices using this API_KEY. User can check the calling request and response statistics from Google Developer Console also. So, performance overhead do not occur for any device.